# VBA: Conditional - Is Nothing

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-2007

There is an `If` condition in a VBA application as seen below:

```
If Not My_Object Is Nothing Then
My_Object.Compute
```

When the code is run in debug mode, I found that the `If` condition returns a true even when `My_Object` has "No Variables".

Could somebody please explain this? I want `My_Object.Compute` to be executed only when `My_Object` exists.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "no variables"? If My_Object is Nothing, it most definitely means it is not pointing to an object. Plus, what's the type definition of My_Object?

Comment: "I want My_Object.Compute to be executed only when My_Object exists." Your wish is hereby granted. (Meaning, is there any scenario where this would *not* be the case?!)

Comment: GSerg, Joel Goodwin, My_Object is an object of a class from an external library. In debug mode, When the If condition is about to be executed, adding a watch to My_Object shows <No Variables>

Comment: Is it an external library any of us would have heard of?

Comment: Are you using "On Error Resume Next" here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Based on your comment to Issun:

> Thanks for the explanation. In my case, The object is declared and created prior to the If condition. So, How do I use If condition to check for < No Variables> ? In other words, I do not want to execute My_Object.Compute if My_Object has < No Variables>

You need to check one of the properties of the object.  Without telling us what the object is, we cannot help you.

I did test several common objects and found that an instantiated `Collection` with no items added shows `<No Variables>` in the watch window.  If your object is indeed a collection, you can check for the `<No Variables>` condition using the `.Count` property:

```
Sub TestObj()
Dim Obj As Object
    Set Obj = New Collection
    If Obj Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Object not instantiated"
    Else
        If Obj.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "<No Variables> (ie, no items added to the collection)"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Object instantiated and at least one item added"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

It is also worth noting that if you declare any object `As New` then the `Is Nothing` check becomes useless.  The reason is that when you declare an object `As New` then it gets created automatically when it is first called, even if the first time you call it is to see if it exists!

```
Dim MyObject As New Collection
If MyObject Is Nothing Then  ' <--- This check always returns False
```

This does not seem to be the cause of your specific problem. But, since others may find this question through a Google search, I wanted to include it because it is a common beginner mistake.

Comment: Similar, by this logic, one would check the `.Value` of a property, than the object itself, since of course the object is instantiated, exists, and therefore `Is Not Nothing`.  I extrapolated that from this answer and solved an issue I was experiencing that was similar to the OP's trying to test a blank string value, which I had to do with `<> ""`, not the `Is Nothing` test.  Thanks - great answer.

Answer (score 12):

Just becuase your class object has no variables does not mean that it is nothing. Declaring an object and creating an object are two different things. Look and see if you are setting/creating the object.

Take for instance the dictionary object - just because it contains no variables does not mean it has not been created.

```
Sub test()

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

If Not dict Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Dict is something!"  '<--- This shows
Else
    MsgBox "Dict is nothing!"
End If

End Sub
```

However if you declare an object but never create it, it's nothing.

```
Sub test()

Dim temp As Object

If Not temp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Temp is something!"
Else
    MsgBox "Temp is nothing!" '<---- This shows
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my case, The object is declared and created prior to the If condition. So, How do I use If condition to check for <No Variables> ? In other words, I do not want to execute My_Object.Compute if My_Object has <No Variables>

Comment: Without seeing your code and what the object is, I'm afraid I don't know how to help you on that.

Comment: A `dict` example! what a surprise :) - good example by the way

Answer (score -1):

In my sample code, I was setting `my object` to nothing, and I couldn't get the "not" part of the if statement to work with the object.  I tried `if My_Object is not nothing` and also `if not My_Object is nothing`.  It may be just a syntax thing I can't figure out but I didn't have time to mess around, so I did a little workaround like this:

```
if My_Object is Nothing Then
    'do nothing
Else
    'Do something
End if
```

Comment: Your experience helped inform me. I had been trying to use `If My_Object Is Not Nothing` also, but your other form looks like it's on the right path. Did you try `If Not (My_Object is Nothing) Then ' Do something`?