# Writing/Reading Dates when using MS Excel VBA to MS Access Database

Tags: sql, excel, vba, database, ms-access

I'm developing an app in MS Excel (2019) to write/read a date to MS Access (2019, same suite) via MS Excel VBA code.
No matter how I enter and format the date, all I get back from MS Access is gibberish.

Everything I found online has missed the point in providing a simple explanation as to what the problem is.

The code provided is stripped down to the elements required to get at the heart of it all.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Conn                 As New ADODB.connection
Public rs                   As New ADODB.Recordset
Public sconnect             As String
Public Const DATABASE_LOC   As String = "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\ASAP\db1"
Public Const DATABASE_NAME  As String = "Database1.accdb"

'MS Access datatable "TheDate" is a ShortDate
'My system date format is 'standard U.S. -  mm/dd/yyyy
'The cell from which result is read is in Date format
'
'Tried:
'ADate = CDate("12/29/2022")
'ADate = #12/29/2022#
'ADate = 'Format("12/29/2022", "mm/dd/yy")
'
'ALL result in: Result IN:  ? Date IN: 12/29/2022    - Access table field: 12:00:18 AM
'Result Out: ? Date OUT: 12:00:18 AM  - Cell "B1" (Date format) cell value: 1/0/1900  12:00:18 AM

Sub TestDateInAndOut()
     TestDateIntoDB
     TestDateOutOfDB
End Sub

Sub TestDateIntoDB()

    Dim SQLString As StringDim ADate As Date

   'option 1
   ADate = CDate("12/29/2022")

   'option 2
   ADate = #12/29/2022#

   'option 3  
   ADate = Format("12/29/2022", "mm/dd/yy")

    SQLString = "INSERT INTO Table1 (TheDate) Values(" & ADate & ")"    '

    OpenSQLConnection ' open connectionrs.Open SQLString, Conn ' & 
recordsetCloseSQLConnections

   Debug.Print "Date IN: " & CStr(ADate)
End Sub

Sub TestDateOutOfDB()
    Dim sSQLSting   As String

    OpenSQLConnection

   sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [Table1]"    ' get all data from Table1

    rs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

    'write the table to worksheetWorksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    'this will have the record just added to DB (first & only record)
    Debug.Print "Date OUT: " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")

    CloseSQLConnections
End Sub

'Open Access DB connection
Sub OpenSQLConnection()
    sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DATABASE_LOC & DATABASE_NAME & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
    Conn.Open sconnect
End Sub

'Close any DB Connection
Sub CloseSQLConnections()
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.CloseSet rs = Nothing
    Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: See discussions in these posts regarding use of `Dim` and `New` in same line: [What is the reason for not instantiating an object at the time of declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8114684/1422451) and [Is the poor performance of Excel VBA auto-instancing a myth?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8489507/1422451)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the best practice of SQL [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-2017) which is supported with ADO library. This approach which is not limited to VBA or MS Access but *any* programming language connecting to *any* backend database allows for binding of values to a prepared SQL query to safely bind literal values and properly align data types:

```vb
...
Public cmd As ADODB.Command ' AVOID DECLARING OBJECT WITH New
...

Sub TestDateIntoDB()

    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim ADate As Date
    Const adDate = 7, adParamInput = 1

    'option 1
    ADate = CDate("12/29/2022")

    ' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARK PLACEHOLDER
    SQLString = "INSERT INTO Table1 (TheDate) Values(?)"

    ' CONFIGURE ADO COMMAND
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = Conn
        .CommandText = SQLString
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    
        ' BIND VALUES
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramDate", adDate, adParamInput, , ADate)
    End With
    
    ' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
    cmd.Execute

    Set cmd = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Date IN: " & CStr(ADate)
End Sub
```

Comment: That's the clean right way to go

Answer (score 0):

Force a format of the string expression for the date value:

```vb
Sub TestDateIntoDB()

    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim ADate     As Date

    ' Option 0.
    ADate = DateSerial(2022, 12, 29)

    SQLString = _
        "INSERT INTO Table1 (TheDate) " & _
        "VALUES (#" & Format(ADate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"

    ' <snip>

End Sub
```