# VBA: test if workbook is nothing

Tags: vba, excel

Edit: My real question is how to test if object was set that was instantiated. I am not really looking to "correct" my code. Its just an example.

I have a function that returns a workbook:

Edit: Added code

```
Sub GetWb() as Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
Set wM = Application.Workbooks.Open("Z:\somepath.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

end sub
```

In another sub I want to check if that object was set properly by the function. I usually do something like this with objects generally:

```
dim w as Workbook
set w = GetWb
if w is nothing then
debug.print "no workbook"
else
debug.print "workbook"
end if
```

However, the `is nothing` test does not work because the object is instantiated, but was not set so it is something, not nothing.

I have resorted to this ugly solution, which works fine:

```
dim w as Workbook
set w = GetWb
on error goto someerrorhandling
if w.name = "" then
end if
on error goto 0
'other code here


someerrorhandling: 
msgbox "no workbook"
```

In other words, I check a property of the object to force an error, or not. There must be a better/cleaner way.

I checked and this link states that the way I am doing it is the best way:
[VBA: Conditional - Is Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472907/vba-conditional-is-nothing)

Comment: Can you post the actual code?  `Sub GetWb() as Workbook` is a syntax error at very least, and `'code here to set the proper workbook` is likely where the issue is.

Comment: I think your solution is close - there may be a better way to write it, but the idea would be the same - catch an error on tyring to access the `Workbook` object. Just wrap it into a `Function` that returns `Boolean` - and you are all set.

Comment: i added code to the function.

Comment: what happens in the first snippet if you comment out `set w = GetWb`?

Comment: Edit: My real question is how to test if object was set that was instantiated. I am not really looking to "correct" my code. Its just an example.

Comment: Just FYI you can't really expect a concrete example with a code sample that is clearly nonsense. Your `Is Nothing` test would work if the code you posted were a function.

Comment: I can't replicate this at all. If `Application.Workbooks.Open` throws I *consistently* have `Is Nothing` return `True` on the variable it was being set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your error handling for GetWB so it returns nothing incase of error, also use Function instead of sub.

```
Function GetWb() As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo errHandler:

    Set GetWb = Application.Workbooks.Open("Z:\somepath.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

errHandler:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set GetWb = Nothing
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If

End Function
```

Comment: While that will solve the issue, my real question is how to test if object was set that was instantiated. I am not really looking to "correct" my code. Its just an example. I am gathering that there isn't a better way and I should either do it my way or return nothing like you state here.

Comment: hmm, but with workbooks, it will never happen, if you do ` Dim x As Workbook` and the check its nothing. Only way to create an instance and not set the value is `Dim x As New Workbook` but this case is useless as it will start spraion err: 429 every time you try to use it without setting any workbook. Overkill is to declare with New keyword and trap error 429.

Comment: @mountainclimber I've also noticed that there is something different when you work with "system" objects like `Workbook` and `Worksheets` collection compared to the objects you create yourself. Not being able to use `Is Nothing` check is one example. Another is - I have generic function to check if item exists in collection and it does not work with `Worksheets`, even though it is theoretically a `Collection` (documentation says that). All you can do with application objects is trial and error to see what works. :-(